# How to limit broadband speed on a cabled connection

Tags: windows-7, broadband

I have a low-speed unlimited Broadband plan shared with my roommate on a UTSTARCOM WA3002G4 4ethernet-wifi-ADSL2+ router (MAC address: 00-1b-da-2e-1b-d9).

He uses the 5e category Ethernet cable to connect to the router. He keeps downloading things at all hours of the day thereby effectively driving down our net speed (as an example, Google's home page takes over 15 seconds to load, and Facebook and Wikipedia take all day long to load).

I have tried to reason with him but failed (he's a bully). I can't even disconnect the cable physically for a short while as the router is in a common room.

**Is there any way to limit his speed?**

I also have a cable and I can connect to the router using that. I am the administrator of the router. I cannot setup my laptop as the gateway/server because I'm usually out late and sleep late and my battery is not very good.

Comment: To try and solve this we would need for you to tell us what the router's model was, and any concrete information you may feel like it is important to solve this. I would ask of you to reformat your text (maybe fix some grammar errors), as it isn't easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

Download Traffic Shaper XP from http://bandwidthcontroller.com/

Another software that can do the same is NetLimiter 2 Lite

For more details you can read the blog at http://www.ehow.com/how_6647489_limit-broadband-connection-speed.html

Comment: Are you affiliated with the first product? You link to it, but not to the second product - why?

Comment: not at all you can use either of them....